# ¿Como se hace para que la máquina lea un décimal y me lo transforme a entero en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

No tengo idea si es que tengo que utilizar alguna libería como lo es math para hacer esto, el punto es que solo necesito que me muestre el entero del decimal... ya lo intenté con una librería pero me arroja 2 valores entero y decimal cuando solo necesito uno de ellos... adjunto el código =

```
import math
print(math.modf(7.56))

----------RUN-----------
(0.5599999999999996, 7.0)
```

Espero alguna ayudita por aquí

Comment: ¿Quieres quedarte solo con la parte entera (7) o quieres redondear al entero más próximo (8 en este caso)? Y por otro lado ¿el resultado, aunque entero, tiene que ser de tipo `int` o quieres que sea de tipo `float`? Es decir ¿7 ó 7.0?

Comment: Solo con la parte entera estimad@, sin redondear

Comment: Entonces `int(numero)` como te han dicho en la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa la función `int`, así:

```
print(int(7.56)) => 7
```

La función recibe como argumento un número o una cadena, interpretandolo como entero.

Answer (score 1):

Otra cosa, puede que necesites mantener los valores devueltos por :

```
math.modf(7.56)
```

que por cierto es una tupla, entonces asignar ambos valores a variables y representarlas en pantalla, solo la parte entera del valor que quieras.

```
pri,seg = math.modf(7.56)
print(f"{seg:.0f}")
```